# Kullback-Leibler divergence of the same image - scipy.stats.entropy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I was calculating kl distance between 3 images histograms:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
from skimage.io import ImageCollection, imread
from skimage import color
import skimage
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

# all images in grayscale
lena = scipy.misc.lena().astype('uint8')
china = skimage.img_as_ubyte(color.rgb2grey( load_sample_image("china.jpg")) )
flower = skimage.img_as_ubyte(color.rgb2grey( load_sample_image("flower.jpg")) )

# histograms for all images
hist_lena, bin_edges_lena = np.histogram(lena, bins = range(256))
hist_china, bin_edges_china = np.histogram(china, bins = range(256))
hist_flower, bin_edges_flower = np.histogram(flower, bins = range(256))
```

When I use scipy.stats.entropy to compare the same image I've got different results:

```
# http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html
from scipy.stats import entropy

print entropy(pk=hist_lena, qk=hist_lena) # nan
print entropy(pk=hist_china, qk=hist_china) # -0.0
print entropy(pk=hist_flower, qk=hist_flower) # nan
```

I was expecting zero (unsigned?) as results.

Am I applying entropy function correctly?
Does it seem correct to apply this function on images histograms?

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  I get -0.0 for the entropy of the lena histogram using scipy 0.14.0

Comment: '0.13.3'...I'll upgrade and run it again.

Comment: upgraded to '0.14.0' and all results are -0.0...thanks Warren.